# Retrieving datas from an ArrayList filled with another ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I got 2 ArrayList objects on my project defined as

```
ArrayList final_list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList temp_list = new ArrayList();
```

I needed to fill my `final_list` with the other one, so I used a loop using `final_list.Add(temp_list)` inside of it, which works fine. 
Here is an exemple about what my `final_list`object looks like after the loop :

[image: list_object]

The fact is I need to process the datas after the loop. So I guess I'll have to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < final_list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6 ; j++)
    {
        // Retrieving my [0,0] , [0,1], ... , [final_list.Count,5] datas
    }
}
```

but this isn't working.
Anyway, I'm even struggling on the correct syntax to use so I already tried hard coded things like `final_list[0,1]` or `final_list[0][1]`to display the `10` value for exemple, but it doesn't work.
How can I manage to do that ?

Comment: Use final_list_player_stats

Comment: The final_list_player_stats is actually final_list , I failed while screenshotting it... Gonna edit my post, thanks for the comment !

Comment: Please note the big blue box on the `ArrayList` [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1), which states: *"We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class."*

Comment: Why do you have `int j` defined twice? You should remove it's definition and assignment that are outside the inner `for` loop.

Comment: generic collections are preferred over `ArrayList`. consider using generics

Comment: `but this isn't working.` **How** is it not working?

Comment: is `temp_list` a  list of lists? could you please give us the code of filling the final list?

Comment: I'm trying to review my code using List<T> class instead.
The `temp_list` is a list of string btw

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a collection (`final_list`), which contains some collections inside. And now you want to process the inner most elements.
First of all, you'd better use generic collections instead of old `ArrayList`.
Generally, handling such a scenario can be done like this:

```
foreach( List<string> innerList in final_list)
{
     foreach( var innerMostItem in innerList)
     {
         // process the element!
     }
}
```

or equivelantely:

```
foreach( var innerList in final_list)
{
     foreach( var innerMostItem in innerList as List<string>)
     {
         // process the element!
     }
}
```

By the way, naming convention of C#, is to use camelCase for variables.

**update**
code snippet above is updated. **Not the type casting in the inner loop**!
Though innerList was originally an `IEnumerable`, it is retrieved from the `final_list` as an instance of `object` class. You need to explicitly cast it to `ArrayList` or you will get an exception.

Comment: `ArrayList` uses `object` to store the types - are you sure you can `foreach` over `innerList`?

Comment: As long as it implements `IEnumerable` there should not be any problem with using `foreach`. I admit that usage of `object` forces the developer to have some casting dance that can be avoided by using generics. However, that problem has nothing to do with `foreach` @RufusL

Comment: The fact that you're using `var` means the type will be `object`, and you cannot `foreach` over an object. Try changing the first `var` to the actual `List<string>` type, and it should work.

Comment: @RufusL Aha, Now I see what you point at. You're right. I missed the fact that `innerList` itself is retrieved as object and needs to be casted.

Comment: I think it should be `foreach(List<string> innerList in final_list) { foreach(string innerMostItem in innerList)`. Are you testing your results? I could be wrong, but those are the types shown in the debug window in the question.

Comment: @RufusL I didn't notice from the image that the inner collections are `List<string>` updated my answer. I've tested your and mine solutions, both work .